# Ricci scalar as a total divergence in 1+1 dimensions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity

I want to show that the Ricci scalar is a total divergence in 1+1 dimensions(in tensor language). How should I proceed?

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! If you could provide us with a little more background on what you understand and what you have already tried, it might help potential answerers assist you.

Comment: Hi! Take a look at the answers to this question here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/303999/derive-einsteins-field-equations-in-one-spatial-and-one-time-dimensions
In 2D the EH action is topological (using the Gauss-Bonnet theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem you can show it's proportional to the Euler characteristic of the manifold, which is constant). This is a result from differential geometry so is best handled with that language.